# foreach item does not seem in c#

Tags: c#, foreach

```
if (Session["GrupId"] != null)
{
    var result= context.User.Where(s => s.DepartmentId == GrupId).Select(s => s.Id).ToList();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
       result.Add(item);
    }               
}
```

If i write item It does not seem out of foreach
I want to write something like this

`var something = context.ResultWhere(s=>s.UserId==item)`
but item does not seem why ?

I am waiting your helps thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to readd items from the list back into the list?

Comment: I realize there's a language barrier, but it's *really* unclear what you're asking.  Can you elaborate?  Maybe show an attempt at code that you've tried and indicate in what way it didn't work?  Perhaps if there's an error message you can tell us the message and on what line it happens?

Comment: Can you show us sample input and the desired output?  That would make your question more clear.  Let's hold off on down votes for a little bit and give OP a chance to get his point across.

Answer (score 5):

You:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
   result.Add(item);
}
```

You cannot modify a `List<>` while you're iterating through it. It will raise an exception from the enumerator saying that its underlying collection was modified.

Answer (score 0):

I make Jeppe words my words also,and i dont know what you are trying to accomplish by adding the same items in the exact order,but if you really must,if you know the type of items in the list,the example i will post will do what you need but again,if you already have the list dont know why add them again and in the same order:

```
            int i = lst.Count - 1;
            foreach (YourClass item in lst.Reverse<YourClass>())
            {
                lst.Insert(i, item);
                lst.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }

            //if you dont know the type make an array

            int i = countries.Count - 1;
            foreach (var item in lst.ToArray())
            {
               lst.Insert(i, item);
               lst.RemoveAt(i);
               i--;
            }
```

this works because we are calling reverse which will retrieve a new list in reverse order
and inside we are adding them in the right place and removing the duplicate